# Select by using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, select-by-attribute

From the below table: **If number of ID_T's counts is more than 2 then, I have to select, same ID_T but DIST value vary of minimum 10 meters**

[image]

Comment: You have to add your best code attempt or your question will be put on hold. Which 11138 rows in your example table would be selected? All 11138 since 82.88-8.13 > 10 (max-min DIST)?

Comment: Dear please check it once BERA

Answer (score 1):

You can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to Group dist values together by id:

```
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict

layer = 'somedata' #Change
fields = ['ID_T','DIST'] #Change

#Create a dictionary of id_t as key, and a list of all dist as value
d = defaultdict(list)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,fields) as cursor:
    for idt, dist in cursor:
        d[idt].append(dist)

#If more than two values in list, and max-min>10 append id_t to a new list
idtlist = []
for idt, dist in d.iteritems(): #d.items() in py3/ArcGIS Pro
    if len(dist)>2 and max(dist)-min(dist)>10:
        idtlist.append(idt)

#A tuple of only one value will cause sql syntax error in selection below
if len(idtlist)==1:
    idtlist.append(-9999)

#Select by idt list
sql = "{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(layer, fields[0]), tuple(idtlist))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=layer, 
                                       where_clause=sql)
```

[image]

Comment: it showing error in 9th line

Comment: @rakesh What is the error message? Is ID_T a text (string) field or number field (Double, INT)?

Comment: it is a string  error

Comment: Ok remove the two lines after comment `#A tuple of only one value ` and change sql line to: `sql = "{0} IN({1})".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(layer, fields[0]), ', '.join("'{0}'".format(i) for i in idtlist))`